# complex object is not passed entirely in api call (Angular + net core 3)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to send to an angular client a complex object. The class of the object is as follows:

```
public class ProductListModel
{
    public int TotPages { get; set; } = 1;
    public int CurPage { get; set; } = 1;
    public long CatId { get; set; } = -1;

    public string Search { get; set; } = "";
    public string Title = "";
    public Category[] Categories;
    public Product[] Products;
    public bool HasCarousel { get; set; }
    public bool Discounted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I defined an interface in angular just as the class:

```
 interface ProductListModel {
  totPages: number;
  curPage: number;
  catId: number;
  search: string;
  title: string;
  hasCarousel: boolean;
  discounted: boolean;
  categories: Category[];
  products: Product[];
}
```

Then I have in my api controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
     [Route(nameof(GetProducts))]
     public ProductListModel GetProducts(int curPage = 1, long catId= -1, bool discounted = false, string search="")
     {
        // uSession.LastUserUrl = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString;
        var plm = new ProductListModel();
        int prodPerPage = 10;

        IQueryable<Product> qp;
        if (search != "")
        {
            plm.Title = "Found Products";
            qp = dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Active && p.Name.Contains(search)).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
        }
        else
        if(discounted)
        {
            plm.Title = "Discounted Products";
            qp = dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Active && p.DiscountPerc>0).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            long catIdNone = dbContext.Categories.Where(c => c.Name == "_None").FirstOrDefault().Id;
            if (catId == -1 || catId == catIdNone)
            {
                plm.Title = "All Products";
                qp = dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Active).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                var catName = dbContext.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == catId).FirstOrDefault().Name;
                plm.Title = "Category: " + catName;
                qp = dbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Active).Where(p => p.CategoryId == catId).OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            }
        }

        int totPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)qp.Count() / prodPerPage);

        if (qp!=null)
        {
            plm.Products = qp.Skip((curPage - 1) * prodPerPage).Take(prodPerPage).ToArray();
        }
        var catl = dbContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToArray();
        if (catl!=null)
        {
            plm.Categories = catl;
        }
        plm.CatId = catId;
        plm.CurPage = curPage;
        plm.TotPages = totPages;
        plm.HasCarousel = (catId == -1) && (!discounted);
        plm.Discounted = discounted;
        plm.Search = search;

        return plm;
     }
```

And finally the angular call:

```
http.get<ProductListModel>(baseUrl + 'api/ajax/GetProducts').subscribe(result => {
  this.ProductListModel = result;
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

but what I get filled are just the non array properties, the arrays products and categories are not even present in result. In Postman I get the same result, see screenshot. Why does this happen and which solution you suggest. Thanks
[image: screenshot of postman]

Answer (score -2):

I found that the missing properties had not the getter and setter. Adding this solved the problem.

Comment: Try what? I have been trying to understand the problem for an hour, then i asked help. While I was reading again my question helped me to find the answer.

Comment: I don't delete the question because it may help others

Comment: yes I saw that theree was no getter and setter and this let me understand the solution. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: you're just polemizing, because I found a solution myself.